# Extending javascript native objects

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I have this code:

```
pPoint = function(x,y){
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}

pPoint.prototype = {
    constructor:pPoint,
    add:function(){
        return this.x+this.y;
    }
}
```

And if I do:

```
a = new pPoint(10,20)
console.log(a.add());
```

Works as expected (returns 30).

However if I do this:

```
Array.prototype = {
    abcd:function(){
        console.log("bla bla testing");     
    }
}
```

And then do this:

```
b = new Array();
b.abcd();
```

It does not work... why?

I know that if I do this works fine...

```
Array.prototype.abcd:function(){
        console.log("bla bla testing");     
    }
}
```

I just dont get why the preivous one works on my pPoint and not in Array...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/wBzhk/

Comment: Setting the prototype in this way (your first example `pPoint.prototype={}`) will have pPoint.prototype.constructor point to Object instead of pPoint. constructor should point to the right function, if you're not using it and you're not expecting other people to extend your code this should not be a problem though but it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Array.prototype` property is not writable.

Therefore, `Array.prototype = ...` has no effect.

You can see this by looking at `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array, 'prototype').writable`, which is `false`.

---

Had you been able to do that, you would lose all of the built-in array methods, since they are properties of the standard `Array.prototype` and not of the new object you're trying to replace it with.

Comment: Oh interesting. So by doing it that way I would be effectively rewriting anything that was set using the "prototype". Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, you'd potentially only loose methods for array instances created *after* the assignment. But that's moot since it can't be done anyway. :-/